# R: Single Column CSV Input Into Multiple Column Data Frame (Some Optional)

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, missing-data

I have a 19 column data frame with 4 optional columns and input from a single column csv file containing up to 40 records. How do I check the input line by line and shunt the input rows as required to allow for missing columns?

```
colnames(phoneticsDF) <- c(
   "Alpha",
   "Bravo" ,
   "Charlie",  # optional
   "Delta",    
   "Echo",     # optional: If Delta begins "A:" then Charlie and Echo missing, shunt input ,add NAs.
   "Foxtrot",
   "Golf",
   "Hotel",
   "India",
   "Juliet",
   "Kilo",
   "Lima",
   "Mike",
   "November",
   "Oscar",
   "Papa",
   "Quebec",   # optional: If Kilo equals "B:" then Quebec missing, shunt input, add NA.
   "Romeo",    # optional: If Romeo contains "-" then Romeo missing, set Sierra = Romeo, shunt input, add NA.
   "Sierra"
)
```

The obvious complication is that if I read in 19 rows at a time and any record is missing data then it will contain the beginning of the next record in rows 16-19?

Please advise?

Comment: For every data point, will the order of columns be same in the input file ?
And do u know which columns are optional and which aren't ?

Comment: `stri_read_lines()` + `purrr::map_df()` + `stri_split_fixed()` + the logic you've described. My opinion is that you're better off doing it this way vs further mangling a mangled `read.csv()` data frame.

Comment: Adarsh, the order of the columns is fixed and the optional columns and rules are indicated in the code outlined in the question.

Comment: How do you map single column csv to multiple column data frame?

Comment: dracodoc, therein lies the problem...

Comment: Do you mean every 19 rows in csv is 19 columns in one row? And the `19` number can change, sometimes it's 18 columns in one row? This is really not what csv should be used. The ideal solution is to fix your csv. At least make the column count fixed. That way you can read the single column csv then rearrange into a matrix with `nrow` and `ncol` parameters. If the csv cannot be fixed, you can write code to at least fill in NA in missing rows to make the column count fixed.

Comment: dracodoc, the csv file is single-column, multiple-record with each record comprising between 15 and 19 rows with only the "rules" to guide which size record is being handled. On the other hand, the destination data.frame contains 19 columns for every record. So, if I read the first 19 lines of the csv file, I use the "rules" to check what (if anything) is missing, set the skip counter to backtrack (if necessary) and then read in the next 19 rows...